# How to add pop-up ads in android?

Tags: android, ads

how can I put pop-up ads to my android project and make it appear when the user closes/opens the app. Something like this - http://i.gyazo.com/5d3efd4f56d9a6c1bd464a9c45c1cfed.png instead of http://goo.gl/b5beFR

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Interstitial Ads which are available in many ads libraries i.e. AdMob or AppFlood. [Interstitial Ad AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial)

Answer (score 0):

as Michal z points out you can use `AdMob`

and load the respective Banner Size:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/banner#banner_size

Download an example from:
https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android_AdMob